# Minificar css e js automaticamente

Tags: javascript, css3, minificação

Anos atrás vi no youtube um vídeo onde o cara apenas escrevia um código no css3 ou no html e se não engano o servidor lia o código minificado, ou talvez criava outro arquivo já minificado.

- Conhecem algo do tipo?
- Como usar?
- Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de minificar o código?

Comment: Pesquise por Gulp, Grunt, Webpack e afins.

Comment: vlw, vou procurar

Comment: Tentei elaborar um pouco mais a pergunta para uma resposta mais completa. Caso tenha sido desnecessário, só desfazer a edição

Comment: Cara o vs code mesmo tem uma extensão que quando vc salva o arquivo ele já cria uma cópia minificada na hora! E tem um tanto de site que faz isso online tb...

Comment: https://www.minifier.org/